# Why is there a hyphen before bash after installing RVM?

Tags: bash, rvm

I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall RVM, in attempts to make a systemwide Ruby and gemset, but it didn't work out as well as I had hoped. I uninstalled RVM, but when I run a command that is not found, it tells me

`-bash: unknown_command: command not found`

rather than

`bash: unknown_command: command not found`

What happened, and how can I fix this? I want it to just say `bash:` and not `-bash:`.

EDIT: I tried a couple things, and ran `bash -login`. After running this, I only got `bash:` but after I logged out of this new login shell, I got `-bash:` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the minus has to stand for login shell, it's perfectly fine to get `-bash:`.

more troubling is that there is no `command not found` try:

```
command_not_found_handle(){ echo "Command not found: $*"; return 127; }
```

Comment: I think I may not have written that clearly. I still get the `command not found` but it says `-bash` instead of `bash`. In any case, is it possible to not automatically run as a login shell?

Comment: it's your terminal emulator configuration, check in preferences

Comment: I found out it is running as a login shell. I can type `logout` to exit the `ssh` session instead of having to type in exit.

Comment: I thought that it was a new thing, but I must not have noticed it before that there was a hyphen before `bash`. Weird.

Comment: `ssh` sessions are login by default, you would have to use some weird logic to make it not login shell and to still use interactive session.